# File size increases on disk image conversion with qemu-img

Tags: virtualbox, disk-image, qcow2, vmdk

I downloaded two Ubuntu cloud image files `xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img` (294M) and `xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.vmdk` (282M) from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/. I modified the .img to make it work on VirtualBox and then converted the file to .vmdk using qemu-img as follows:

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O vmdk xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1-new.vmdk
```

I noticed that file size of the converted .vmdk file increases to 1GB. I want to have the file size more or less the same as the original file. Did I miss something here? Since I am relatively novice to image formats and conversion tools, I appreciate for any useful information on tools and techniques to achieve this.